# Combine two columns of numbers in dataframe into single column using pandas/python

Tags: pandas

I'm very new to Pandas and Python.

I have a 3226 x 61 dataframe and I would like to combine two columns into a single one.

The two columns I would like to combine are both integers - one has either one or two digits (1 through 52) while the other has three digits (e.g., 1 or 001, 23 or 023). I need the output to be a five digit integer (e.g., 01001 or 52023). There will be no mathematical operations with the resulting integers - I will need them only for look-up purposes.

Based on some of the other posts on this fantastic site, I tried the following:

```
df['YZ'] = df['Y'].map(str) + df['Z'].map(str)
```

But that returns "1.00001 for a first column of "1" and second column of "001", I believe because making "1" a str turns it into "1.0", which "001" is added to the end.

I've also tried:

```
df['YZ'] = df['Y'].join(df['Z'])
```

Getting the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'join'
```

I've also tried:

```
df['Y'] = df['Y'].astype(int)
df['Z'] = df['Z'].astype(int)
df['YZ'] = df[['Y','Z']].apply(lambda x: ''.join(x), axis=1)
```

Getting the following error:

```
TypeError: ('sequence item 0: expected str instance, numpy.int32 

found', 'occurred at index 0')
```

A copy of the columns is below:

```
1   1
1   3
1   5
1   7
1   9
1   11
1   13
```

I understand there are two issues here:

- Combining the two columns
- Getting the correct format (five digits)

Frankly, I need help with both but would be most appreciative of the column combining problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need convert columns to `string`, add `0` by [`zfill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.zfill.html) and simply `sum` by `+`:

```
df['YZ'] = df['Y'].astype(str).str.zfill(2) + df['Z'].astype(str).str.zfill(3)
```

Sample:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Y':[1,3,5,7], 'Z':[10,30,51,74]})
print (df)
   Y   Z
0  1  10
1  3  30
2  5  51
3  7  74

df['YZ'] = df['Y'].astype(str).str.zfill(2) + df['Z'].astype(str).str.zfill(3)
print (df)
   Y   Z     YZ
0  1  10  01010
1  3  30  03030
2  5  51  05051
3  7  74  07074
```

If need also change original columns:

```
df['Y'] = df['Y'].astype(str).str.zfill(2)
df['Z'] = df['Z'].astype(str).str.zfill(3)
df['YZ'] = df['Y'] + df['Z']
print (df)
    Y    Z     YZ
0  01  010  01010
1  03  030  03030
2  05  051  05051
3  07  074  07074
```

Solution with `join`:

```
df['Y'] = df['Y'].astype(str).str.zfill(2)
df['Z'] = df['Z'].astype(str).str.zfill(3)
df['YZ'] = df[['Y','Z']].apply('-'.join, axis=1)
print (df)
    Y    Z      YZ
0  01  010  01-010
1  03  030  03-030
2  05  051  05-051
3  07  074  07-074
```

And without change original columns:

```
df['YZ'] = df['Y'].astype(str).str.zfill(2) + '-' + df['Z'].astype(str).str.zfill(3)
print (df)
   Y   Z      YZ
0  1  10  01-010
1  3  30  03-030
2  5  51  05-051
3  7  74  07-074
```